# Proving $\mathbb{T=\{R^2,\varnothing\}}\cup\{G_k,k\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is not a topology.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the class $\mathbb{T=\{R^2,\varnothing\}}\cup\{G_k,k\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of substes in the $\mathbb{R^2}$ plane. Where $$G_k=\{(x,y)|x>y+
k\}$$

I have already proven $\mathbb{T}$ is a topology, however, if $\mathbb{T=\{R^2,\varnothing\}}\cup\{G_k,k\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ it is not a topology anymore, why? I can't prove it.

Comment: It’s the usual argument: find a sequence of numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$ that convege to a number outside of $\mathbb{Q}$. Take $k$ as this sequence and build the infinite union of these sets.

Comment: I have taken the sequence $R_n=m/n$ where $m$ is the smallest integer so that $m/n<a$, therefore, $(m+1)/n>a$ and therefore $|a-m/n|\lt 1/n$. Now it is easy to see that $R_n$ converges to $a$. If I take $a=\pi$ then I do have that sequence of numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$ that converges to a number outside of $\mathbb{Q}$. However I still don't see why the infinite union of the sets $G_{R_n}$ is not in $\mathbb{T}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a decreasing sequence $\mathbb{Q}\ni a_n\searrow \pi$ (slight modification of yours), and consider the family of sets $G_{a_n}$.

By definition $G_{a_n}\in \mathbb{T}$.If $\mathbb{T}$ were a topology, then the union of the $G_{a_n}$ would again be in the topology.

But $\bigcup G_{a_n}=G_{\pi}$ (is this clear to you?) and $G_\pi$ is not in $\mathbb{T}$ as $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Thus we have a contradiction and hence $\mathbb{T}$ is not a topology.

Comment: Of course, you also mean for $a_n > \pi$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yup. I added "decreasing" to make the answer correct